# PHP arrays flatten multidimensional array by key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, flatten

Here is my initial array:

```
$arr = array(
array('model'=>'123', 'garment'=>'coat', 'title'=>'aaa'), 
array('model'=>'123', 'gender'=>'men', 'title'=>'aaa'), 
array('model'=>'123', 'brand'=>'adidas', 'title'=>'aaa'),
array('model'=>'345', 'garment'=>'jacket', 'title'=>'bbb'),
array('model'=>'345', 'gender'=>'kids', 'title'=>'bbb'),    
array('model'=>'345', 'brand'=>'nike', 'title'=>'bbb'),     
array('model'=>'678', 'garment'=>'trainers', 'title'=>'ccc'),
array('model'=>'678', 'gender'=>'kids', 'title'=>'ccc'),    
array('model'=>'678', 'brand'=>'', 'title'=>'ccc')  
);
```

I would like to get to:

```
$result = array(
array('model'=>'123', 'garment'=>'coat', 'gender'=>'men', 'brand'=>'adidas', 'title'=>'aaa'),
array('model'=>'345', 'garment'=>'jacket', 'gender'=>'kids', 'brand'=>'nike', 'title'=>'bbb'),
array('model'=>'678', 'garment'=>'trainers', 'gender'=>'kids', 'brand'=>'', 'title'=>'ccc')
)
```

Would you please kindly help me - thank you. Here is my attempted solution, but I'm running out of memory when trying to source large arrays.

Here is step 1:

```
    //---------------------- STEP 1 ------ 
$result = array();  
foreach($arr as $line) {
    $result[] = $line['model'];

}

$result = array_values(array_unique($result));
```

Here is step 2:

```
//---------------------- STEP 2 ------ 
foreach($result as $r) {
    $inter = array();

    $inter['model'] = $r;

    foreach($arr as $line) {
        if ($r == $line['model']){
            if (!isset($inter['title']) && isset($line['title'])) {
                $inter['title'] = $line['title'];
            }                               
            if (!isset($inter['garment']) && isset($line['garment'])) {
                $inter['garment'] = $line['garment'];
            }
            if (!isset($inter['gender']) && isset($line['gender'])) {
                $inter['gender'] = $line['gender'];
            }    
                if (!isset($inter['brand']) && isset($line['brand'])) {
                        $inter['brand'] = $line['brand'];
                }
        }
    }

    if (!isset($inter['title'])) {
        $inter['title'] = '';
    }   
    if (!isset($inter['garment'])) {
        $inter['garment'] = '';
    }   
    if (!isset($inter['gender'])) {
        $inter['gender'] = '';
    }   
    if (!isset($inter['brand'])) {
        $inter['brand'] = '';
    }


    $results[] = $inter;
    unset($inter);
}

unset($result);
return $results;
```

Comment: is "model" a sort of unique code?

Comment: Use a simple `foreach` loop ....

Comment: yeap. in the and I have a list of unique values of '123', '345' and '678'and associated parameters next to them

Comment: I've used foreach, but the initial array is around 3000 lines, I'm run ning out of memory - I need a smarter solution here

Comment: Running into memory issues definitely has to be mentioned in your question. Otherwise you'd only get the obvious code answers, if any at all (it really is on the homework level of difficulty). Show your code!

Comment: here you are - code added, apologies for not mentioning running out of memory

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
array('model'=>'123', 'garment'=>'coat', 'title'=>'aaa'), 
array('model'=>'123', 'gender'=>'men', 'title'=>'aaa'), 
array('model'=>'123', 'brand'=>'adidas', 'title'=>'aaa'),
array('model'=>'345', 'garment'=>'jacket', 'title'=>'bbb'),
array('model'=>'345', 'gender'=>'kids', 'title'=>'bbb'),    
array('model'=>'345', 'brand'=>'nike', 'title'=>'bbb'),     
array('model'=>'678', 'garment'=>'trainers', 'title'=>'ccc'),
array('model'=>'678', 'gender'=>'kids', 'title'=>'ccc'),    
array('model'=>'678', 'brand'=>'', 'title'=>'ccc')
);
//var_dump($arr);   
$arrRes = array();
$arrSort = array();

foreach($arr as $key => $v){

$key = array_search($v["model"],$arrSort,true);
if($key === false){
    //key empty , insert model 
    $arrRes[] = $v;
    $arrSort[] = $v["model"];
    }
else{

    foreach($v as $subKey => $subv){
        if($subKey!="model"){       
            $arrRes[$key][$subKey] = $subv;
        }
    }   
}   

}
echo "<pre>";   
var_dump($arrRes);  
echo "</pre>";
```

I tried about 8000 lines , if your loop is run out of memory, clearly it got logic errors
also , I don't think you can preserve the same string key name in an array.

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks ever so much! I still have an issue with the memory though + error.log shows "signal Segmentation fault (11)". At least it shows that this is not to do with the code itself, but rather to do with memory settings. Will dig deeper

Comment: if you find this answer is helpful , give me a green tick show the answer is correct , thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
array('model'=>'123', 'garment'=>'coat', 'title'=>'aaa'),
array('model'=>'123', 'gender'=>'men', 'title'=>'aaa'),
array('model'=>'123', 'brand'=>'adidas', 'title'=>'aaa'),
array('model'=>'345', 'garment'=>'jacket', 'title'=>'bbb'),
array('model'=>'345', 'gender'=>'kids', 'title'=>'bbb'),
array('model'=>'345', 'brand'=>'nike', 'title'=>'bbb'),
array('model'=>'678', 'garment'=>'trainers', 'title'=>'ccc'),
array('model'=>'678', 'gender'=>'kids', 'title'=>'ccc'),
array('model'=>'678', 'brand'=>'', 'title'=>'ccc')
);

$new_arr = array();

foreach ($arr AS $tmp) {
  $this_model = $tmp['model'];
  if (!isset($new_arr[$this_model])) { $new_arr[$this_model] = array(); }
  $new_arr[$this_model] = array_merge($new_arr[$this_model], $tmp);
}
print '<pre>';
var_dump($new_arr);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: But this will not/never work for 'title', because only the last (overwritten) value will stay.

Comment: What I meant with my comment is, you can't flatten it like this if title is different [123]:title='a', [123]:title='b' ... only 'b' will be left over and 'a' gets lost.

Comment: yeah, I see now. I'm afraid I would need a whole lot in one line, including title. But hey, thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

My method assumes the input subarrays are in batches of 3.
The first empty associative array in `array_replace()` serves to establish the key order desired by the OP.
I am using a splat operator `...` so php5.6+ is required.
The splat operator delivers all three subarrays in the chunk at once.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bea370ea1cdd9e9245243d20c6e87eeabe8c0bbc))

```
$arr = array(
    array('model'=>'123', 'garment'=>'coat', 'title'=>'aaa'), 
    array('model'=>'123', 'gender'=>'men', 'title'=>'aaa'), 
    array('model'=>'123', 'brand'=>'adidas', 'title'=>'aaa'),
    array('model'=>'345', 'garment'=>'jacket', 'title'=>'bbb'),
    array('model'=>'345', 'gender'=>'kids', 'title'=>'bbb'),    
    array('model'=>'345', 'brand'=>'nike', 'title'=>'bbb'),     
    array('model'=>'678', 'garment'=>'trainers', 'title'=>'ccc'),
    array('model'=>'678', 'gender'=>'kids', 'title'=>'ccc'),    
    array('model'=>'678', 'brand'=>'', 'title'=>'ccc')  
);
$key_order=['model'=>'','garment'=>'','gender'=>'','brand'=>'','title'=>''];
foreach(array_chunk($arr,3) as $a){
    $result[]=array_replace($key_order,...$a);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'model' => '123',
    'garment' => 'coat',
    'gender' => 'men',
    'brand' => 'adidas',
    'title' => 'aaa',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'model' => '345',
    'garment' => 'jacket',
    'gender' => 'kids',
    'brand' => 'nike',
    'title' => 'bbb',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'model' => '678',
    'garment' => 'trainers',
    'gender' => 'kids',
    'brand' => '',
    'title' => 'ccc',
  ),
)
```